# Create clickable file to run docker using Platypus

Tags: bash, docker, executable, clickable, platypus

I'd like to create clickable file for Mac users to run docker container. I want to use [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to achieve this:

My setup:
[image]

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

docker run -d --name nginx nginx:latest

echo ">>>>> done!"
```

[image]

After clicking `.app` file nothing happens:

[image]

Any ideas why it doesn't work?